# Who are these humans fighting over the planet Mul?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

There is a very cool space battle scene during which an armada of human warships are fighting a single huge alien ship. Who are the alien race and what happens to them? What led to this battle in first place?

It seems like the humans are technologically at a disadvantage here and have to resort to using doomsday weapons to avoid huge losses. Is that really the case?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The novelisation refers to the *"War against the Southern Territories".*

> This was the army humanity had fronted in one of the worst wars of its
> entire checkered history—the War against the Southern Territories. It
> was largely because of this war, with its years of violence and
> astronomical numbers of casualties on both sides, that humanity had
> firmly rededicated itself to pursuing peace if at all possible. Peace
> bought with the bloodiest of prices, Okto-Bar remembered his father
> saying. He continued to read the list of ships and their captains.
>
> <sub><sup>[Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets: The Official Movie Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33216612-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets)</sup></sub>

And the film itself identifies the baddies (over Mül) as being **"the [Arysum-Kormn](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Arysum-Kormn)"**

> [The war against the Arysum-Kormn led to the destruction of Planet Mül](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/57dc5323-d5a3-403c-bcf3-37c393d4ddf5).

[image]

---

Nothing more specific is known other than that humanity won, and was so horrified by the death and destruction that it then dedicated itself to the cause of galactic peace.